# asymptotic of a geometric like series

Tags: calculus

I am looking for an asymptotic of $\sum_{n\ge r}2^{-3n+O(\sqrt n)}$ when $r\to +\infty$.
Any idea how to obtain such an asymtotic? Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume by asymptotics you mean Landau notation asymptotics. In which case, would it not be the case that $\Sigma 2^{-3n+O(\sqrt{n})} \leq \Sigma 2^{-(3-\epsilon)n}$ for some small $\epsilon$ depending on $r$? And therefore you can find a $O(f)$ upper bound by using that geometric series, and then find a $\Omega(g)$ lower bound with the same technique?

Comment: @saulspatz I don't think so. Isn't it the case that $-n\pm\sqrt{n}\approx -n$?

Comment: @Valborg. I do not manage to write a rigorous proof that $\sum_{n\ge r}2^{-3n+O(\sqrt n)}\sim\sum_{n\ge r}2^{-3n}$ (with $\epsilon$, $\forall$ and so on)

Comment: @Valborg  You're right.  It's past my bedtime, I think.

Comment: @joaopa Don't prove the asymptotic at that stage, that is far too hard. Just get an upper bound on each term of the sum, and thus an upper bound on the sum itself. Then do lower bounds.

Comment: @saulspatz Trust me, I'm getting there. I've been making a lot of typos recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rough attempt at turning my comment into a proof:

The term $O(\sqrt{n})$ is an abuse of notation; what should be written at that stage is a specific function whose growth is dominated by $\sqrt{n}$ in magnitude in the very specific way given in the Landau notation definitions. Convince yourself that this means that whatever function $f(n)$ should be in place of that $O(\sqrt{n})$ actually obeys the following compound inequality, for some positive real constant $k$ and for all sufficiently large $n$:

$$
-k\sqrt{n}\leq f(n)\leq k\sqrt{n}
$$

Then what can we say about the exponent $-3n+O(\sqrt{n})$? This is actually bounded by the compound inequality:

$$
-3n\left(1+\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\leq-3n-k\sqrt{n}\leq -3n+O(\sqrt{n})\leq -3n+ k\sqrt{n}\leq-3n\left(1-\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$

Thus, depending on the constant $k$ (which is fixed with respect to the limit we are about to take) and the variable $r$, if we know that $n\geq r$ we can say that, for $\epsilon=\frac{k}{\sqrt{r}}$, the follwoing compound inequality holds:

$$
-3n\left(1+\epsilon\right)\leq -3n+O(\sqrt{n})\leq-3n\left(1-\epsilon\right)
$$

But this implies that $\sum\limits_{n\geq r}2^{-3n\left(1+\epsilon\right)} \leq \sum\limits_{n\geq r}2^{-3n+O(\sqrt{n})} \leq \sum\limits_{n\geq r}2^{-3n\left(1-\epsilon\right)}$, for the sufficiently large $n$ discussed earlier. These upper and lower bounds are geometric series, and thus a closed form can be written down for them, which will be purely in terms of $k$, a constant that was originally obfuscated in the $O(\sqrt{n})$, and the variable $r$, which will decide the asymptotic behavior of the sum.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what happens wether we have $-3n^2+O(n)$ instead of $-3n+O(\sqrt n)$. In such a case, there is no easy closed form formula.